# How to do PayPal transaction between two users in React.js?

Tags: reactjs, paypal

I am entirely new to making E-commerce website. Already I have built the basic interface and all required features. I am stuck in one thing. Basically I am working on Paypal integration. At the moment, the money comes to my account after checkout since I have setup with my credentials. But in my Website, one can be a publisher too. How do I ensure that the money goes from the customer to the publisher account? As for the admin, since I am the admin so I already configure with necessary credentials. But what about those publishers who sign up in my website? Thanks. Just give me an idea. I am using React.js in my front end.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the official [react-paypal-js](https://paypal.github.io/react-paypal-js/?path=/docs/example-paypalbuttons--default)

When creating the order, specify the recipient `payee` [with an email or merchant id](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integration-features/pay-another-account/).

A server integration to create the order is not required, but more robust for the usual reasons.